# Y86 assembly save new value to global syntax

Tags: assembly, y86

My professor has not provided much in the way of Y86 examples only IA32.  I have managed to figure everything out for my assignment except for saving my final answer to the global variable result.  It is declared as follows.

.align 4

result: .long 0

My answer is stored in the %ebx register and I need to transfer it to my result global.  It makes sense to me to just use "rmmovl %ebx, result" but I get the error "not a number: result."  What  is the correct syntax to accomplish what I am trying.

Thanks!

Comment: You of course need the reverse direction as in the duplicate question, e.g. `irmovl $result, %eax; rmmovl %ebx, (%eax)`.

Comment: Oh wow that should have been obvious.  Thanks again jester!  Sorry for the similar question.